# PIP From command line error

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I'm trying to download modules using the pip command in the CMD. I have pip and python both added to my path directory. I don't know how to get this to work though, I've tried upgrading my pip but just keep getting exceptions. Does anyone know how to solve this?

I'm very new to working from the command line...
[I tried working around the initial fatal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID2Zk.jpg)
[Then I tried upgrading my pip but it didn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiG3P.jpg)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the error stack that you are getting, it is better to add the stack to the question as the link to the screenshot may be broken later.

Comment: Did you try to open your cmd as admin?

Comment: You may try to run cmd as administrator

Comment: Not only might the screenshot link be broken later, reading red on black is difficult. It does not make anyone want to strain their eyes enough to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Sorry guys, didn't think about that. How do you run as admin @ettanany?

Comment: @JoshDautel Just right click on cmd then choose "Run as administrator"

Comment: RightClick over CMd -> run as Admin

Answer (score 2):

@Josh,

Try this.

1. Open your cmd prompt with admin rights (if you have privileges).

   This can be done by right-clicking on the start menu and select the admin cmd in the context box provided for windows 8 and 10.

   For Windows 7 you click Start>All Programs>Accesories, then right-click cmd prompt and Run as Administrator.
2. In the prompt, you should see something like **C:\WINDOWS\system32>**
3. If pip is installed to your path, type in "**python -m pip install yourPackageNameHere**"

Example given to install the twilio [package](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) (which is pretty cool):

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install twilio

This should take care of it.

For some other helpful information, you can check out these sites.

pip users guide

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-packages

  or

  The Python documentation (which is a programmer's best friend in time of need)
- https://www.python.org/

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Josh, you should be able to find the admin cmd by right clicking the start menu and the context box should contain it for windows 10.

Comment: I found it, thank you so much. Downloaded a bunch of packages already. Appreciate it !!